# How to initialize a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I'm making a simple Binary Tree program, and I would like to initialize the left and right node. I've been trying to do it like this:

```
class Tree{
     Tree* left = new Tree();
     Tree* right = new Tree();
}
```

This is supposed to give me an accessible memory on the heap which I can use to access the left and right nodes, correct? However, it doesn't seem like that's the case. I've also tried doing this through constructors too with no luck.

Is there a way to properly initialize a class in C++?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Looks like you've written yourself an infinite recursion there. Constructor calls constructor, which calls constructor... What's your real goal here? Perhaps we can suggest an alternative. Most logical of which is set them to `nullptr` and fill them out later when you know you need a branch.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. All I'm trying to do is be able to insert a key into either the left node and right node. But I can't do that if the left and right nodes are not initialized in the first place, right? 

Edit: I'll try that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `class` like this

```
class Tree
{
 public:
    Tree* left;
    Tree* right;
    Tree() // default constructor
    { 
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    Tree(Tree *Tleft,Tree *Tright) // parameterised constructor
    { 
        left = Tleft;
        right = Tright;
    }

    ~Tree() // Destructor
    { 
        delete left;
        delete right; 
    }
};
```

you can use `default constructor` to initialize the `Tree class` as `nullptr`, and `parameterised constructor` to initialize with user values, ie with `Tree` nodes,

```
void main()
{
    Tree *node1 = new Tree(); //using default constructor
    Tree *node2 = new Tree(); //using default constructor
    Tree *node3 = new Tree(node1, node2); // using parameterised constructor
}
```

Comment: Generally right, please correct obvious error in your post. :-)  `Tree Tright` should be `Tree *Tright`, `null` should be `NULL` or `nullptr`.

Comment: You don't need to check for null before deleting. Just delete.